# The operation could not complete. (Alamofire.AFError error 9.)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

On a network request handled by Alamofire, I often get this error:

> The operation could not complete. (Alamofire.AFError error 9.)

**Has anyone a clue about what this error 9 is?**

I suppose `AFError` being an enum and conforming to protocol `Error`, this error 9 could be the raw value of the `createURLRequestFailed(error:)` case (which is the 10th case in this enum).
[AFError enumeration reference](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Enums/AFError.html)

I then implemented some delegate methods in `EventMonitor`, like

```
public func request(_ request: Request, didFailToCreateURLRequestWithError error: AFError)

public func request(_ request: Request, didCompleteTask task: URLSessionTask, with error: AFError?)

public func request(_ request: UploadRequest, didFailToCreateUploadableWithError error: AFError)

public func request(_ request: Request, didFailTask task: URLSessionTask, earlyWithError error: AFError)
```

but none of these seem to be triggered for this error (especially the first one, which seemed a good fit).

How can I debug this error and find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Can you post how you're printing this error? It's likely you've cast it to an `NSError` or something similar, which loses content. If you just print the `AFError` instance directly you should see a proper description.

Comment: @JonShier You're right, that's exactly what happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, where you can debug this by casting the AFError to an NSError or URLError and from there on debug what it is that actually went wrong.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3068